# Windows Workflow Foundation v4.5: Receives within ParallForEach activity causes duplicate bookmark name error

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity, workflowservice

Each receive activity has its own correlation, yet I still got the error.

Here is a brief description of the workflow.

> Main workflow:  Process -> Receive(StartProcess), create instance &
>   generate PID as correlation -> ParallelForEach, taskID 1 to 10,
>   run(Task Workflow) -> Complete
>
> Task workflow: InitCorrelation(PID, taskID) -> Receive(CheckReady) ->
>   Complete.

When the workflow starts, I will keep getting this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: A bookmark with the name
>   'CheckReady|{SPOC}ITaskMgmt' already exists.

I am under the impression that as long as the correlation is set correctly, this should work.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is the expected behavior.

To resolve this issue, instead of running multiple instances of the same activity within ParallelForEach, the workflow starts multiple instances of anther workflow.  Therefore, ParallelForEach is no longer need, since individual workflow instances can run in parallel.